# iRedMail 0.9.9 with Apache2, how to get the web interface working

Tags: apache2, iredmail

Could anyone tell me how, or point me into a working tutorial on how to get iRedMail working when using Apache2?

Installation is succesful, all I need now is the web interface. We cannot use Nginx because there are a lot of websites hosted on this server, so we have to stick to Apache.

I hope someone can tell me how we can get the web interface working with Apache.

- iRedMail version: 0.9.9
- Deployed with: installer
- Linux/BSD distribution: Ubuntu 18.04
- Backend:  MariaDB
- Web server: Apache2

Been Googling for 2 days now without finding a working solution unfortunately.

The URL that I installed it on should be webmail.mydomain.com

Best regards

Answer (score 5):

The working example for me is below:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

...

WSGIDaemonProcess iredadmin user=iredadmin threads=15
WSGIProcessGroup iredadmin
WSGIScriptAlias /iredadmin /opt/www/iredadmin/iredadmin.py/
Alias /iredadmin/static /opt/www/iredadmin/static/
<Directory /opt/www/iredadmin/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

...

</VirtualHost>
```